# Ошибка  при выборке изображения из хтмл

Tags: jquery, javascript

> `$("#vremenno img").eq(i).attr("id") is undefined`

ФайрБаг выводит такую ошибку.

Вот мой код:

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayPodkid.length; i++) {
    $('#vremenno').prepend(arrayPodkid[i]);
}
for (i = 0; i < arrayPodkid.length; i++) {
    if (!$('#vremenno').eq(i).attr('src')) {
        if (resultPodkid > parseInt($('#vremenno img').eq(i).attr('id').match(regV), 10) / 10) {
            resultPodkid = Math.floor(parseInt($('#vremenno img ').eq(i).attr('id').match(regV), 10) / 10);
            var m = parseInt($('#vremenno img ').eq(i).attr('id').match(regV), 10);
        }
```

В ХТМЛ лежит следущее

```
 <div id="vremenno">
 <img id="103" height="260" width="174" src="images/рубашка.jpg">
 <img id="102" height="260" width="174" src="images/рубашка.jpg">
 </div>
```

Comment: regV как глобальная переменная задана

Comment: а в arrayPodkid что лежит? + вы уверены, что картинок не меньше, чем размер массива?

Comment: arrayPodkid массив с картинками.
Как раз это и проверяю

Comment: По желанию как то работает, 1 раз из 10 такое выходит. Не знаю как отследить, с дебаггером сидеть очень долго, ведь я не знаю, выйдет ли ошибка сейчас или нет

Comment: Во-первых, запись такого вида - `$('#vremenno').eq(i)` - наталкивает на мысль, что у вас несколько элементов div имеют одинаковый идентификатор! Это уже является грубой ошибкой.
Во-вторых, выкладывайте логически законченные отрывки кода, дабы избежать лишних вопросов и избавить от сеансов телепатии.

Comment: id разные же. В данном случае: 102, 103

Comment: 1. Зачем идет проверка на src у div'а? Если проверка идет у img (опечатка), то до внутреннего условия дело просто не дойдет.
2. Если все-таки туда попадаем, то что в regV? и Чем инициализирована переменная resultPodkid?
3. Задачу в двух словах хотя бы сформулируйте. После этого, совершенно точно количество строк кода уменьшится вдвое, понимание в чем ошибка придет само.

Answer (score 2):

Предложу такой рефакторинг:

```
for(var i in arrayPodkid)
  $('#vremenno').prepend( arrayPodkid[i] );

for(var i in arrayPodkid) {
  var img = $('#vremenno img').eq(i);
  if(!img.attr('src')) {
    if (resultPodkid > parseInt( img.attr('id').match( regV ), 10) / 10 ) {
      resultPodkid = Math.floor( parseInt( img.attr('id').match(regV), 10) / 10 );
      var m = parseInt( img.attr('id').match( regV ), 10);
    }
  }
}
```

[@Радик Камалов](/users/4844/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2), не брезгуйте пробелами и отступами) Сильно повышают читаемость кода. В min-версии сожмете, если надо будет.

Кстати, спасибо [@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis) :) "`$('#vremenno').eq(i)`" - тоже ошибка, попытался логично исправить.

*Оффтоп: как ни старался, не понял, что этот код должен сделать. Убрал явные ошибки и оптимизировал.*